# ES case insensitive boolean field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 1m record where one column is boolean. It contains three values. `FALSE, TRUE, [Blank]`.

I want this field to be treated as boolean. Due to the case, it is not treated as boolean. I understand that ES supports true or "true" as boolean and no analyser on this.

Is there any other way to handle my records? Records are dynamic too. As load arrives, it has to be stored appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a way to achieve this using an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) that transforms your field.

You can create an ingest pipeline with a [`convert` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/convert-processor.html) like below. When converting to boolean, the convert processor ignores the casing, so `"TRUE"` will be converted to true. Same for `"FALSE"`. Add `ignore_missing: true` to ignore null values:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/bool-pipeline
{
  "description": "converts FALSE/TRUE to boolean",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "convert" : {
        "field" : "bool",
        "type": "boolean",
        "ignore_missing": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then when you index your documents, you can just specify the pipeline in the query and the documents will flow through the `bool-pipeline` before being indexed.

```
PUT index/_doc/123?pipeline=bool-pipeline
{
    "bool": "TRUE"
}

PUT index/_doc/456?pipeline=bool-pipeline
{
    "bool": "FALSE"
}

PUT index/_doc/789?pipeline=bool-pipeline
{
    "bool": null
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying this. Can I use this to load data from logstash also?

Comment: Yes, in Logstash you can specify the [`pipeline` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-pipeline) as well

Comment: Thanks. It works when I do the same way as in your example. When I add pipeline setting under Elasticsearch object in Logstash config, it says `pipeline with id [%{bool-pipeline}] does not exist`. But `GET` returns the pipeline. Individual update works. I added like `pipeline => "%{bool-pipeline}"`

Comment: Simply add `"pipeline" => "bool-pipeline"`, no need for string expansion with `%{...}`

Comment: Yep, Fundamental problems :( Should I learn Logstash to get going in ES? I am more concentrated on search now.

Comment: ES is for search, Logstash is for loading data, so it depends on what you need.