# Logstash pipeline doesn't exist

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am getting into this problem from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61708339/es-case-insensitive-boolean-field).

I created the pipeline as below.

```
{
    "bool-pipeline": {
        "description": "converts FALSE/TRUE to boolean",
        "processors": [
            {
                "convert": {
                    "field": "secure_flag",
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "ignore_missing": true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My valid values are FALSE, TRUE, [Blanks]

I am able to retrieve the pipeline.

I added as below in Logstash config.

```
 input {
    file {
        path => "/Users/gibbs/Documents/search/mini_system.csv"
        start_position => beginning
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        columns => [
               "secure_flag",
               "mini_system_key",
               "hw_contract_end_date"
        ]
        separator => ","
        }
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["path", "host"]
  }
}
output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
        index => "mini_system"
        document_id => "%{mini_system_key}"
        pipeline => "%{bool-pipeline}"
    }
}
```

But when I load the data, it throws the below error.

```
    [2020-05-10T16:13:05,691][DEBUG][o.e.a.b.T.BulkRequestModifier] [gopir-mac-1] failed to execute pipeline [_none] for document [mini_system/_doc/50395971|1038832]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pipeline with id [%{bool-pipeline}] does not exist
    at org.elasticsearch.ingest.IngestService.executePipelines(IngestService.java:407) [elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.ingest.IngestService.access$000(IngestService.java:75) [elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.ingest.IngestService$3.doRun(IngestService.java:384) [elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:692) [elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar:7.6.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_231]
```

I am clueless. I am trying for hours now.

Any suggestions please?

And when I checked the logs, I see that error in elastic search logs. Logstash has a single liner of it.

Comment: See my comment in that other question you're referring to ;-) Just use `pipeline => "bool-pipeline"` without string expansion

Comment: @Val I solved it after hard try. That `%` mislead me actually

Comment: @Val Can I do the below? `if _source.secure_flag == %{FIELD} {
            pipeline => "bool-pipeline"
        } else if "partners" == %{FIELD} {
            pipeline => "partners-pipeline"
        }` It is not working.

Comment: I suggest you create a new question since your initial need has been solved.

Comment: @Val [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61725620/logstash-specify-more-than-one-pipeline) it it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ingest pipeline name is `bool-pipeline`, you should use it in the `elasticsearch`, not `%{bool-pipeline}`.

The `%{FIELD}` is for use with event dependent values, which is not your case, using `%{bool-pipeline}` will make logstash try to extract the value with the name for the ingest pipeline from a field named `bool-pipeline` in your event and since the field does not exists you are getting this error.

Comment: I am still trying to understand the second paragraph more. If possible, please help with it. What is event and what value is it related to an example.

Comment: An event is everything that pass through a logstash pipeline, every line in a log file is an event for logstash, in your case for example, the field `mini_system_key` probably has different values for each line in your csv, and you are using this value as the `document_id` in elasticsearch, the way to access the value of a field in logstash is using the format `%{FIELD}` because the value of this field depends on each event (log line, for example). You can read more in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#sprintf)

Comment: Thanks. It is a nice explanation

Comment: And, Can I specify more than one pipeline in Logstash's ES output plug-in?

Comment: @Gibbs You can only specify one pipeline per ES output, but you can specify several ES outputs with if/else logic

Comment: @Val I will try this.