# Logstash - specify more than one pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want different fields to be processed in different way.

I have two pipelines. One is to process boolean values, another one is to convert a string to array.

```
 output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
        index => "mini_system"
        document_id => "%{mini_system_key}"
        if [source] == "secure_flag" {
            pipeline => "bool-pipeline"
        } else if "partners" == %{FIELD} {
            pipeline => "partners-pipeline"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to do this. But I am not able to achieve this and couldn't find a reference also.

Sample documents:

```
key,partners,secure_flag,date_added
5369922730525,"1002300,1009747,12359,2285459",FALSE,2020-03-31T14:00:00Z    
2218100624,,FALSE,2020-03-31T14:00:00Z
```

here,

"1002300,1009747,12359,2285459" is partners.
FALSE is secure_flag.

Partners pipeline:

```
{
  "description": "Converts \"a,b,c\" to [\"a\", \"b\",\"c\"]",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "split" : {
        "field" : "partners",
        "separator": ",",
        "ignore_missing": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @Val Please check my edit

Comment: Thanks, it would be great to have the header names as well

Comment: @Val I simplified the sample further with column names

Comment: Thanks, and what does your `partners-pipeline` do ?

Comment: @Val Added that in the question. It converts "a, r, s " to ["a", "r", "s"] -> multivalue field

Comment: Ok, then we really don't need two pipelines, but simply have two processors in the same pipeline. You can have as many processors you want in a pipeline and you'd not need any logic. See my updated answer

Comment: I thought that. But I got confused that both pipelines will be applied to the terms. Isn't the case?

Comment: Nope, each processor only works on one field (the one specified in `field`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot apply logic inside plugin configurations, but you can definitely have several output using if/else logic:

```
output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
    if [source] == "secure_flag" {
        elasticsearch {
            action => "index"
            hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
            index => "mini_system"
            document_id => "%{mini_system_key}"
            pipeline => "bool-pipeline"
        }
    } else if [field_xyz] == "partners" {
        elasticsearch {
            action => "index"
            hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
            index => "mini_system"
            document_id => "%{mini_system_key}"
            pipeline => "partners-pipeline"
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You don't actually need any logic, but simply add both of your processors in the same pipeline:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/mini-pipeline
{
  "processors" : [
    {
      "convert" : {
        "field" : "secure_flag",
        "type": "boolean",
        "ignore_missing": true
      }
    },
    {
      "split" : {
        "field" : "partners",
        "separator": ",",
        "ignore_missing": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And then simply use this configuration

```
output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
        index => "mini_system"
        document_id => "%{mini_system_key}"
        pipeline => "mini-pipeline"
    }
}
```

Comment: You are quick :) What is `[source]` does it mean source field in CSV if my input is CSV file?

Comment: Yes, that can be any field from your document that you want to test

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me where I can refer such options like `[source], [tags], [type], [@metadata]` these are the things I am seeing in many posts. But couldn't get the exact thing. `[source]` is a placeholder of the current field name that is being processed.

Comment: Those are nothing special, just field names from your document. See this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html

Comment: ok, I am little confused. Actually here `secure_flag` and `partners` are csv columns to which pipeline has to applied.

Comment: Can you show two sample documents that you need your pipelines to handle?